# Ruby on Rails change array display order

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm trying to find a way to display an array in a **Rails view** as follows:

```
 [  1  ] [  4  ] [  7  ] [  10  ]
 [  2  ] [  5  ] [  8  ] [  11  ]
 [  3  ] [  6  ] [  9  ] [  12  ]
```

In my controller, I have an array defined as

```
 def index
 @myArr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]
 end
```

Since this display order is not typical for a table, I am unsure how to proceed to accomplishing this.

I would like to know the following:

1. What's the best way to display the values (above) in a table on my Rails view page using the order that I have requested in the code? Simply looping over the `@myArr` with `<tr>` and `<td>` results in the following:

   ```
   [  1  ] [  2  ] [  3  ] [  4  ]
   [  5  ] [  6  ] [  7  ] [  8  ]
   [  9  ] [  10 ] [  11 ] [  12 ]
   ```

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to do it in Ruby, then:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12].each_slice(3).to_a.transpose.flatten
# => [1, 4, 7, 10, 2, 5, 8, 11, 3, 6, 9, 12]
```

But I wouldn't do it this way. I would use CSS3 `flexbox` properties to do it.

Comment: Sawa, can you expand on how you would do this with CSS3 properties? Thanks in advance. I appreciate it