# Sorting objects Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to sort some items that I am receiving from my database. Currently, I have a series of objects that get returned from my `Tool` model. Right now, I am retrieving some **tools** from my database, by using the following code (in my **toolkit_controller**):

```
 def index 
 @tools = Tool.order('name ASC').all
 end
```

This seems to be working fine and as intended. When I do this, I get the following result set (omitted some of the extra results for clarity).

```
 [#<Tool id: 1, name: "Hammer", description: "A basic hammer", 
 created_at: "2013-07-07 16:46:13",
 updated_at: "2013-07-07 16:46:15">, 
 #<Tool id: 2, name: "Mallet", description: "A fancy 
 mallet", created_at: "2013-07-07 16:46:13", updated_at: "2013-07-07 16:46:15">, 
 #<Tool id: 3, name: "Screwdriver", description: "A screwdriver", 
 created_at: "2013-07-07 16:46:13", updated_at: 
 "2013-07-07 16:46:15">, 
 #<Tool id: 4, name: "Torch", description: "A cheap torch", created_at: 
 "2013-07-07 16:46:13", updated_at: "2013-07-07 16:46:15">, ....]
```

What I'm struggling with right now is how to display my tools in a vertical fashion (rather than horizontal) on my **erb** page. To help paint a clear picture of the sort order I want, please take a look at this post: [Ruby on Rails change array display order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17268512/ruby-on-rails-change-array-display-order).

My display code is as follows:

```
<%= @count = 0 %>

<div>
    <% @tools.each do |t| %>
        <% @count = @count+1 %>

            <div class="individualTool">
                <%= t.name %> <%= @count %>
            </div>

       <% if @count == 4 %>

           <% @count = 0 %>
       </div>

       <div class="row-fluid">

       <% end %>

   <% end %>
```

As you can see, the above code works fine to display the tools by name from left-to-right (e.g. Hammer, Mallet, Screwdriver, Torch), but my goal here is to display them from top-to-bottom, in an order as seen here: [Ruby on Rails change array display order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17268512/ruby-on-rails-change-array-display-order).

In the post that I linked, someone suggested using `.each_slice(3).to_a.transpose.flatten` (to try and correct the sort order), but when I tried that on the `@tools` that were being returned, I received an error message stating that the `element size differs`.

Any ideas on how I can accomplish this would be great!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand the question, but isn't this more of a CSS matter than a programmatic one? If its only a matter of how its shown.

Comment: I'd like to try and fix the order of my `tools` programatically if that's possible. If I could correct the order in which they exist [#Tools ... ], then I think my problem would resolve itself and the code would work.

Comment: Definitely a display issue to resolve with CSS.  ***Don't put display logic into your controller!!!***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All, thank you for the input. I guess I'm still a bit confused as to why this wouldn't be considered a ruby **sorting** problem of which we could solve. After doing a bit more research on my own, I figured out how to solve the problem. The solution works as follows:

In my index method of the **toolkit_controller**, I have the following:

```
def index
@tools = Tool.order('name ASC').all
aAllTools = []

for i in @tools
  aHashedTool = {}
  aHashedTool["name"] = i.name
  aHashedTool["description"] = i.description
  aAllTools << aHashedTool
end


@outcome = aAllTools.each_slice(4).to_a.transpose.flatten  # Corrects the order. 
logger.debug "#{@outcome}"  # Verified. Order is now correct.

 end
```

By using the code above I was able to simply loop over the values like I had been doing in my question and everything seems to work. If there is a more optimal solution (or perhaps I should post a CSS question as well), then I would be happy to entertain it.  Thanks again and I do appreciate your replies.